# Determine which command button was clicked to open userform

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have two command buttons (`cmd1` and `cmd2`) on `userform1`, when clicked each show the same userform (`userform2`). Within the `initialize` or `load` sub is it possible to determine which command button was clicked on `userform1` and therefore show the form differently? I imagine the code in either the `initialize` or `load` sub on `userform2` to have the following skeleton:

```
if (cmd1 was clicked)
' do stuff relating to 1
elseif (cmd2 was clicked)
' do stuff relating to 2
else
' error handling
End if
```

The respective "`stuff`" could be moved into the event handler for `cmd1` and `cmd2` however, if the method described above can be used it will be a lot simpler and cleaner.

Comment: Alternatively, if you can use the `Activate` event instead, you could have a Commandbutton variable in userform2 that is set by Userform1 before it shows userform2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `Public Variable` in `UserForm1` and then test it in `UserForm2_Initialize Event`.
Something like this in UserForm1:

```
Public whatsclicked As String
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    whatsclicked = "CommandButton1"
    UserForm2.Show
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    whatsclicked = "CommandButton2"
    UserForm2.Show
End Sub
```

And then in UserForm2:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Select Case UserForm1.whatsclicked
    Case "CommandButton1": MsgBox "CommandButton1 loaded form."
    Case "CommandButton2": MsgBox "CommandButton2 loaded form."
    Case Else 'Do something else
    End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it also without public variable.

i won't show an example where you can simply write something in a cell or hidden sheet, instead i just pass the wanted info directly .

this time whatsclicked is the name of a label in userform2,

in userform1, before calling userform2:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
load UserForm2
with UserForm2
    .whatsclicked.caption= "CommandButton1"
    .Show
end with
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
load UserForm2
with UserForm2
    .whatsclicked.caption= "CommandButton2"
    .Show
end with
End Sub
```

Of course, you will have to hide the text of whatsclicked to the user (same color as font or background...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ActiveControl` for this as when you click a control it becomes active/focussed:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Debug.Print Me.ActiveControl.Name
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Debug.Print Me.ActiveControl.Name
End Sub
```

So more in line with your example:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call DoStuff
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Call DoStuff
End Sub

Private Sub DoStuff()
  select case Me.ActiveControl.Name
    case "CommandButton1"
      ' do stuff relating to 1
    case "CommandButton2"
      ' do stuff relating to 2
    case else
      'error etc.
  end select
End Sub
```